# How does a linear rescaling alter a polytope equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose a have a polytope $P$  defined by $Ax \leq b$. Suppose $x \in \mathcal{X} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid l_i \leq x_i \leq r_i, i = 1,\ldots, d\}$ i.e a hyperrectange in $\mathbb{R}^d$. How would $A$, $b$ change if I were to apply a linear rescaling to $x$ so that $x_i^{*} = \theta_0 x_i + \theta_1$?

In particular, I have a sampling scheme in mind for the design and analysis of a computer experiment - I want to compute a maximin design with boundaries defined by a polytope (see section 5.5 of [this book](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/santner.1/TJS-BJW-WIN/master-driver.pdf)). My parameter space is defined by a polytope $Ax \leq b$ but it is much more conveniet to construct the design with all the $x_i$ scaled to the unit interval (solves the problem of inputs 'dominating' each other. Hence, I want to construct my design points on $x^{*} \in [0,1]^d$ then simply rescale: $x = \text{diag}(r-l)x^{*} + l$ to generate inputs to a computer model .

In essence, if I linearly rescale my hyperrectangle to be a unit hypercube, how does this change the inequality which defines my polytope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thought I'd realised that the solution to this is quite straightforward.

If $x = diag(r-l)x^{*} + l$ then I can simply substitute this into the inequality which defines my polytope.

$$Ax \leq b$$
$$\implies A \left(\text{diag}(r-l)x^{*} + l\right) \leq b  $$
$$\implies A \,\text{diag(r-l)}x^{*} + Al \leq b $$
$$\implies A \,\text{diag(r-l)}x^{*} \leq b - Al $$

Hence we can say $A^{*} = A \,\text{diag(r-l)}$ and $b^{*} = b - Al$ define an equivalent polytype on $[0,1]^d$ by $A^{*} x^{*} \leq b^{*}$